# SPFx extension custom dialog showing old text once you close the dialog and open it again in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, spdialog

This is a issue that recently started to happen. I have SPFx extension which uses custom dialog. When user clicks on button, I have dialog box that opens up with table and a close button which user can use to close the dialogue box.

But I am suddenly seeing an issue where if I click on the button to open the dialogue box again, I will see the same table twice and the okay button twice as well. Everything was working fine up-to now so I am not sure why I am suddenly seeing this behavior. If I refresh the SharePoint page and click on the button, it will open just 1 table and 1 okay button so it seems like when I close the dialog box it is still holding on to the information rendered before and displays it again.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

I have tried searching for way to clear the dialog box before I render the table but I can't find anything on it. Any idea would be greatly appreciated. I am following this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/spfx-creating-custom-dialog-boxes-without-a-javascript-framework. I have changed the onExecute to the following:

```
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
      
      switch (event.itemId) {  
        case 'COMMAND_1':  
                const dialog: CustomDialog = new CustomDialog();  
                dialog.itemUrlFromExtension = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName("FileRef");  
                dialog.otherParam = "This is parameter passed from Extension"  
                dialog.show()

                
          break;  
        case 'COMMAND_2':  
          Dialog.alert(`${this.properties.sampleTextTwo}`);  
          break;  
        default:  
          throw new Error('Unknown command');  
      }  
    }  
  }
```

[image]

Comment: could you share your code here? It's hard to guess why this is occurring without seeing how you implemented it.

Comment: Are you passing dynamic content to the dialog box? If yes, clear the dynamic information state property on close of dialog & again set new value to the state property on click of button (to open dialog again).

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov  I have added the tutorial I am following as well as the code changed I made to get the error

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have added more details to the post

Comment: Did you miss `var html:string = "";` line at the start of `render()` function?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no I have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog box is showing old content/table again because you are "concatenating" the new content to previous content using:

```
this.domElement.innerHTML += html;
```

Instead of `+=`, use `=` like given in below code:

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = html;
```

This is an easier way than setting the `innerHTML` twice in render method.

Comment: I prefer this solution more. Thanks, Ganesh.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing similar issue- adding `this.domElement.innerHTML = "";` in render() function fixed the issue.